# Transmission line model proof?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations, models, radio-frequency

Why 2 distributed lines is represented with series inductor and resistor along with parallel capacitor and resistor? What is the motivation for that?

In circuit theory I Knew the assumptions to reduce Maxwell's equations to KVL and KCL, Can I see something similar for distributed element?

Any suggestions for papers or books is appreciated.

Note: I am studying RF circuits in range 0.8-2 GHZ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why 2 distributed lines is represented with series inductor and resistor along with parallel capacitor and resistor? What is the motivation for that?

Current through the wires is associated with (let's not discuss which causes which) a magnetic field, and we can represent that with an inductor. Potential difference between the conductors of the line is associated with an electric field, and we can represent that with a capacitor. Similarly loss mechanisms can be associated with current along the line (the series resistor) and with leakage current in the dielectric (the shunt conductor).

> Any suggestions for papers or books is appreciated.

I learned from Ramo, Whinnery, and Van Duzer, which is generally meant as a text for a first electromagnetics course. It includes quite a bit of material connecting electromagnetics to circuits. But it could be a bit fast paced to use for self-teaching.

Comment: "Potential difference between the conductors of the line is associated with an electric field, and we can represent that with a capacitor." I think that's not the reason why we use the shunt capacitance. I mean, consider a battery whose + terminal is connected to one end of one ideal wire, and whose - terminal is connected to one end of another ideal wire. Then there's a p.d. between the conductors/wires, but that's not because of some capacitance present, right? As far as I know, the shunt capacitance is present if the wires have net charge (and thus there's a p.d. across the wires).

Comment: @AlejandroNava, the capacitance doesn't cause the p.d. The capacitance models the energy stored by the field, and the effect of having to store or discharge that energy in order to change the p.d.